# Why aren't my circles centering?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have circles on my webpage that represent percentages. There is some text inside the circles which is the percentage amount. There is also some text underneath the circles which is a short description. I am able to center all the text. However, I can't center the circles. I'm using:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

From what I read online, this is the best way to center things on your website, especially as it makes it responsive. I tried using percentages for the circle but that doesn't help either. For example, if I do:

```
margin-left: 20%;
```

the circle looks centered on the iPhone 6, but not on the iPhone 5 and 4.

I'm pasting more extensive code below. I hope this will help you understand my problem better.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .ipad-mini-cirlces {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .knob-container canvas {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
.circle-text {
  margin-left: 107px;
  width: 200%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  text-align: left;
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .circle-text {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .knob-container {
    margin: 27px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-left: 60px;*/
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .circle-text {
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 160%;
    margin-top: 114px;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
.knob-container canvas {
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section clearfix">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row ipad-mini-cirlces">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="knob-container">
              <input class="knob" data-fgcolor="#5cb85c" data-thickness=".1" value="20%" data-displayInput="false" data-readOnly="true">
              <div class="knob-text">
                <span>10-30%</span>
              </div>
              <div class="knob-text circle-text">
                <label>Saved through improved workflow processes <a href="http://bframe.com/software/security/roi-cost-savings/">Find Out More</a>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="knob-container">
              <input class="knob" data-fgcolor="#5bc0de" data-thickness=".1" value="7.5%" data-displayInput="false" data-readOnly="true">
              <div class="knob-text">
                <span>5-10%</span>
              </div>
              <div class="knob-text circle-text">
                <label>Savings on current cost of reusing of original production material <a href="http://bframe.com/software/security/roi-cost-savings/">Find Out More</a>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="knob-container">
              <input class="knob" data-fgcolor="#d9534f" data-thickness=".1" value="15%" data-displayInput="false" data-readOnly="true">
              <div class="knob-text">
                <span>10-20%</span>
              </div>
              <div class="knob-text circle-text">
                <label>Savings through a more polished preparation ahead of the edit <a href="http://bframe.com/software/security/roi-cost-savings/">Find Out More</a>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row ipad-mini-cirlces">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="knob-container">
              <input class="knob" data-fgcolor="#f0ad4e" data-thickness=".1" value="60%" data-displayInput="false" data-readOnly="true">
              <div class="knob-text">
                <span>40-80%</span>
              </div>
              <div class="knob-text circle-text">
                <label>Savings on current cost of distributing media <a href="http://bframe.com/software/security/roi-cost-savings/">Find Out More</a>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="knob-container">
              <input class="knob" data-fgcolor="#f0ad4e" data-thickness=".1" value="60%" data-displayInput="false" data-readOnly="true">
              <div class="knob-text">
                <span>40-80%</span>
              </div>
              <div class="knob-text circle-text">
                <label>Savings on current cost of distributing media <a href="http://bframe.com/software/security/roi-cost-savings/">Find Out More</a>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="knob-container">
              <input class="knob" data-fgcolor="#8cc63e" data-thickness=".1" value="60%" data-displayInput="false" data-readOnly="true">
              <div class="knob-text">
                <span>30-50%</span>
              </div>
              <div class="knob-text circle-text">
                <label>Savings on current cost of media storage and handling <a href="http://bframe.com/software/security/roi-cost-savings/">Find Out More</a>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your container has to be the full width (obviously). Your circle should be a block element (`<div>`) or `display: block;` otherwise `margin: 0 auto;` wont take effect

It's also possible to give your circle `display: inline-block;` and your container `text-align: center;`